# Maven Build Error - try-with-resources is not supported in -source 1.5

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, try-with-resources

This is my simple code from a Maven project which has try-with-resources.I use eclipse as my IDE.

```
public class Hello {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try(FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream("ANC")){

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When I build this using `clean package -U` it gives me the following error.

```
Hello.java:[11,20] try-with-resources is not supported in -source 1.5
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable try-with-resources).
```

However,I have my java compiler to be set at Java 1.8 and in Jave Build path JRE System Library is also JDK 1.8.Still this error persists.

This is my POM file ( minus the junit dependency )

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.commonutil</groupId>
  <artifactId>PropertyFile</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>PropertyFile</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
</project>
```

Note : Setting the target and source in pom.xml did not help either.
Any help regarding this is appreciated.Thank you.

Comment: @Oleg Tried setting the source and target in pom.xml  too.Did not change the outcome.

Comment: Be careful with that your IDE is not synchronized with the pom.xml, so any IDE specific modifications will not apply to maven, if you use maven to build your project.

Comment: Then you did something wrong, this is the solution.

Comment: @YannisSermetziadis Thankl  you for the reply.Any idea on how to synchronize the IDE with Maven.I am using maven plugin for eclipse.

Comment: @Ran_Macavity, you can try the maven-eclipse-plugin to generate the eclipse project files based on your pom.xml and maven configuration (settings.xml). From IDE to maven synchronization is probably a job of the IDE to provide, so I do not think there is a standard way.

Comment: Just a hint: maven-eclipse-plugin is deprecated. Better use a most recent version of m2e integration. That should work..

Answer (score 7):

You need to specify the java source version, so the correct flag value is used by the compiler plug-in. For example:

```
<properties>
  <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
</properties>
```

Comment: Not to forget. `<maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>`..

Comment: In addition to the above information, those two maven-compiler-plugin properties map to the javac -source and -target flags.
javac -help
-source <release>          Provide source compatibility with specified release
-target <release>          Generate class files for specific VM version